# how to very exact match on complex lines

Tags: awk, sed, grep, perl

we have the following file:

```
more test.txt

export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx8g -Xms8g"
export KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS="-XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX
:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80"
```

how to verify the lines:

```
export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx8g -Xms8g"
```

and

```
export KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS="-XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX
    :MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80"
```

are exists in the file - test.txt

of course , we can do

```
grep -q 'export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx8g -Xms8g"' test.txt 
[[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo "line in file"


grep -q 'export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="export KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS="-XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX
        :MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80"' test.txt 
[[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo "line in file"
```

**but this approach is very clumsy**

Comment: Why is it clumsy to use a tool that’s built to search for text to search for text? You’d just have to escape any regex characters, but since you already know what text you’re searching for, that’s easy.

Comment: If you're trying to find the *exact* line, use grep options `-F` and `-x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#! /bin/bash

env - bash -c '. test.txt; [ -n "$KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS" ] && [ -n "$KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS" ]'
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     echo 'OK'
else
    echo 'ERROR'
fi
```

Comment: this are only the variables , what about all values that variables are represented ?

Comment: KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS_ should be KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS

Comment: @yael I doubt that you will get the answer you are looking for without a reasonable definition of "clumsy"...

Comment: since I not get other idea / answers I prefer to delete my question , do you want also to delete ?

Comment: @yael That is a strange reaction after not even an hour and after not improving your question but if you feel that is the right thing to do then just delete your question...

Comment: its better if you remove first and then I